# Json Request in iphone

Tags: iphone, json

Actually I am working on the Couchdb .Till now i have used the Local server for Connecting to he CouchDb . Now I need to Connect to the remote server of couchdb . For this I need to send the User Name And Password Through the Json .

How can we use authenticated basic Json post ?

Comment: how can i tell you in iPhone??

Comment: it depends how your server accepts the format of json... just put the format needed in your question.

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. I suggest using Google-translate to get an English version of your question as I am guessing English is not your main language due to the question asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the post method (post the username and password )

code like …. try

```
NSString *postStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", username, password];
NSData *postData = [postStr  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *requesting = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:YourURLObject];
[requesting setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[requesting setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[requesting setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[requesting setHTTPBody:postData];
NSError *error;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requesting returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add JSON framework if you are using iOS5 sdk else download [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) and add it to your project and import "SBJSON.h"

Case 1: Using JSON Array

```
NSArray *credentials = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"uName", @"pWord",nil];
NSString *jsonString = [credentials JSONString];
```

Case 2: Using JSON Dictionary

```
  NSDictionary *credentials = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"uName", @"pWord",nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"UserName",@"password",nil]];
NSString *jsonString = [credentials JSONString];
```